# jQuery process groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have several groups of checkboxes that are all related. More specifically, it is a permission system. Each user group has their set of permissions, so Admin gets view/read/create, Member gets view/read/create, and so on. Each group will have checkboxes for each permission, so as to select which groups can do what.

Processing with PHP is cake, can just do `name="permission[$group_id][]"` and that's pretty much it. However being not very fluent with Javascript, I'm having a bit of trouble processing it with jQuery in the same fashion. Ultimately I need to be able to pass the checkboxes to a PHP script with AJAX. I also have to be able to populate the checkboxes with AJAX/Javascript.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   //Select all checkboxes whose names begin with 'permission[', and serialize them for correct ajax transport
   data: $(":checkbox[name^='permission[']").serialize()
   ...
});
```

It will encode your checkboxes name automagically.

Comment: This worked. On the PHP end I used the parse_str function to get the array I was looking for. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

First you can select your checkboxes by name to find which have been checked, something like:
$('input[name=yourname]:checked').val();
http://api.jquery.com/val/

to get your values and loop them into an array,
or you can 'serialize' your form:
http://api.jquery.com/serialize

then you can submit your data via post with:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Hope this helps. If you post some code I can give you more direct support.